# Query to display top rated artist albums in MS Access

Tags: sql, ms-access, select

I have two tables in a music db. `[Artists]` has *PK artist_id* and *artist_name*. `[Albums]` has *FK artist_id*, *album_id*, *album_name*, and *rating*.

I want to `select MAX(rating), album_name` and `GROUP BY [album].artist_id`. Access prevents me from displaying the *album_name* because it must be included in the `GROUP BY` function in addition to the *artist_id* which defeats the point.

My query:

```
SELECT albums.artist_id, MAX(albums.rating) 
FROM Albums 
GROUP BY albums.artist_id;
```

The above query selects the top album for each artist but does not include the name of the album. I've also attempted `JOIN`s to get the *artist_name* to display with no luck.

Could you please advise me on how I can select the required fields?
EDIT: I got it working with this query:

```
    SELECT Album_name, rating, Artists.artist_name
    FROM Albums
    INNER JOIN Artists ON Albums.artist_id = Artists.Artist_id
    WHERE rating = (select MAX(rating) from Albums i 
    WHERE i.artist_id = albums.artist_id)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to achieve this -

---

#### Using a joined subquery:

One possible method is to use an `inner join` on a subquery that selects the maximum rating for each `artist_id`:

```
select t1.*
from albums t1 inner join
(
    select t2.artist_id, max(t2.rating) as mr
    from albums t2
    group by t2.artist_id
) q 
on t1.artist_id = q.artist_id and t1.rating = q.mr
```

Note that this will return multiple records if two or more albums share the same rating.

---

#### Using a correlated subquery:

Another method is to use a correlated subquery which attempts a select a record with a greater rating than the current record, and return the records for which such subquery returns no results (represented by the `where not exists` clause):

```
select t1.*
from albums t1 where not exists 
(
    select 1 from albums t2 
    where 
    t1.artist_id = t2.artist_id and t1.rating < t2.rating
)
```

---

#### Using a `LEFT JOIN` with unequal join criteria:

Finally, you could also use unequal join criteria with a `left join` in the following way, returning records for which there are no records on the right of the join which meet the join criteria:

```
select t1.* 
from 
    albums t1 left join albums t2 on 
    t1.artist_id = t2.artist_id and t1.rating < t2.rating
where 
    t2.rating is null
```

This example can only be represented in MS Access in the SQL view, as the MS Access Query Designer cannot display joins which have equal join criteria (i.e. where one field equals another).

This example is similar in operation to the correlated subquery, but the selection is performed by the join, rather than within the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: These are unique answers and a wakening call that I need to start thinking outside the box! I don't foresee any issues using my query above these considering my database is small... But I will experiment with them.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you're looking for.

```
SELECT albums.artist_id, albums.album_name, artists.artist_name, MAX(albums.rating) 
FROM albums INNER JOIN artists ON albums.artist_id = artists.artist_id
GROUP BY albums.artist_id, albums.album_name, artists.artist_name;
```

Comment: Thank you! This solves one problem but my primary issue is not being able to display the album_name.

Comment: Ooops, I misread.  I thought you needed the artist name.  Updated it to include the album name.

Comment: This causes the problem I was having with Access. When I include the album name in the GROUP BY clause it shows the max rating per album, not per artist. EDIT: I got it working with another query. Thank you for the help!